# Can you lock the Unity screen after 15 minutes, not shown in "Brightness & Lock" dropdown?

Tags: brightness, lock-screen

In Ubuntu 13.10, the Brightness & Lock dialog lets you lock the screen after idle time of 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 30, and 60 minutes. Is it possible to set a different idle time not shown in this list, say, 15 minutes?

(Frankly, it's silly to present only a few options like this.... Why not permit an arbitrary number of minutes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install dconf-editor (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) and go to

org gnome settings-daemon plugins power

Click number besides idle-brightness and it will allow you to change it.

[image]

Speculation on my part: the lack of options in the GUI is to not make it too crowded and "experienced" users that need more refinement will probably know about dconf.

Answer (score 1):

For those scared of GUI's:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/idle-brightness somenumber
```

The maximum value is an arbitrary number. The numbers are counted in minues. So

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/idle-brightness 300
```

Is the equivalent to 5 hours.